# firebase real time DB unread messages count with multiple filters

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Current fire base query in Java Script:

```
unread = 0
messagesRef.orderByChild("read").equalTo(1).on("value", function(ysnapshot) {
 unread = ysnapshot.numChildren();
});
```

Works fine.

What If i had to add another orderByChild of "sender" equal to "employee" ?

I want to retrieve unread messages count , which is read = 0 and sender is employee
.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way to filter like this in firebase. They suggest to denormalise your data to allow for this kind of control. See this [blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html) for a in depth description or [this section of the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data).

That aside you might be able to get away with a simple filter. If you don't have too much data to go through, filter could do the job for you.

```
const employeeMail = unread.filter(({ sender }) => sender === 'employee')
```